# What was Jabba the Hutt's pet?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification

What is this thing?  It was shown in Jabba's Palace, sitting with Jabba, and seemed like it was probably some sort of favored pet.

[image]

Is it sentient?  Does it have a name, or an identified species?

Comment: It's Star Wars.  Lucas named each creature in the Cantina, every bounty hunter on the Star Destroyer, and probably every extra at Jabba's Palace.  OF COURSE the 'pet' has a name.

Comment: To its intelligence it seems to be similar to a parrot it can respond seemingly intelligently but is limited in what it actually understands.  It can know how to laugh and mimic others but does not seem to create its own ideas.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

That is [Salacious Crumb](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Salacious_B._Crumb). To quote the Star Wars Wiki:

> Salacious B. Crumb was a [Kowakian monkey-lizard](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kowakian_monkey-lizard) employed as a court jester for Hutt crime lord Jabba Desilijic Tiure.

And yes, Jabba the Hutt has a full name.

Regarding their sentience, the Star Wars Wiki says:

> Although they had no established culture, Kowakian monkey-lizards were quite intelligent, and despite their silly, cruel nature, they were considered sentient by many sentientologists in the galaxy, although there was much debate over their possible sentience.

Comment: So that's what a monkey-lizard is! It is way uglier than all the insults implied

Answer (score -5):

I believe it's a gremlin like creature that jabba found and kept as long as he pleased.

He looks like a gremlin also so that jabba apparently thought was cute like a puppy so kept it.

Comment: Can you provide some evidence for this?

Comment: Flagged as NaA since OP is looking for "a name, an identified species"; this answer does not provide a name and links to a more general creature (or the movie _Gremlins_, I honesty can't say for sure), which is not exactly relevant to Star Wars canon. The remaining speculation isn't backed by any more pertinent information.